# Understanding Proposition 2 proof in CO-H-Structures on Moore spaces of type(G,2)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Here is the paper I am reading :

> [image]

And here is the proposition I am speaking about:

> [image]

And here is theorem 4.1 in Hilton book:

> [image]

> [image]

And here is Lemma 1:

> [image]

**My Questions are:**

1-Why $C(X)$ which is the set of comultiplications of $X$ is equal to $j_{*}^{-1}(\triangle)$?

2-why $j_{*}^{-1}(\triangle)$ is in one-one correspondence with Ker$j_{*}$?

3-Why Image$\partial \approx \pi_{1}(X;X\times X, X \vee X).$

Could anyone help me in annswering those questions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really given enough information about the notation in the paper for your question to be self-contained.  It's also hard to understand your confusion, because most of your questions are either definitions in the paper or basic concepts in abstract algebra, which is a prerequisite for the article.

In any case, maybe this will help:

1. The definition of $\mathcal{C}(X)$, given in the paper, is the following:

> For an associative co-$H$-space, the set $\mathcal{C}(X)$ of comultiplications of $X$ consists of the homotopy classes of maps $\phi: X \to X \vee X$ such that $j \circ \phi = \Delta$, where $j: X \vee X \to X \times X$ is the inclusion and $\Delta: X \to X \times X$ is the diagonal.

Since $j_*: [X, X \vee X] \to [X, X \times X]$ is given by postcomposition with $j$, we see that $\phi \in [X, X \vee X]$ is a comultiplication iff $j_* \phi = \Delta$ iff $\phi \in (j_*)^{-1}(\Delta)$.  This answers question 1.

2. The fiber of $j_*$ at any point such as $\Delta$ is either empty or a torsor for $\ker j_*$.  This is a general fact about group homomorphisms: if $f: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and $h \in H$, then any two elements of $f^{-1}(h)$ differ by an element in $\ker f$.  By the Lemma 1 you quoted, $j_*$ is onto, so $(j_*)^{-1}(\Delta)$ is nonempty; hence, it is in bijection with $\ker j_*$.  This answers question 2.
3. From the exact sequence we learn that $\partial$ is injective and it is tautologically a surjection onto its image.  So $\partial$ is an isomorphism from $\pi_1(X; X \times X, X \vee X)$ to $\operatorname{Image}(\partial)$.  This answers question 3.